# Have more standard apps in "Limit apps and home screen"

Tags: samsung, background-process, battery-saver

I like Samsung's power saving option "Limit apps and home screen", but 4 apps is just not enough. As a result, some apps shut off when you close which I would like to keep running.

Can you add more than 4 apps to the set of apps that are allowed to run in the background somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.  Even in developer options, the maximum is 4.

[image]